# Difference between pseudograph and multigraph in graph data structure?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

Some authors say pseudograph and multigraph are same, and some say both are different. I just read on the wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multigraph.
What is the exact difference between them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the link you have provided:

> a multigraph (in contrast to a simple graph) is a graph which is permitted to have multiple edges (also called parallel edges), that is, edges that have the same end nodes. Thus two vertices may be connected by more than one edge.

and

> a pseudograph is a multigraph that is permitted to have loops.

So the differentiating factor is that a multigraph may not have loops, only self-edges. While pseudograph can have both.